# The best way to communicate between desktop app and windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service, ipc

I am working on app (c++) that consist from two parts.

- Control Panel working under restricted user account (with UAC enabled)
- Windows Service, performing some useful tasks

I need to collect user preferences in control panel and send them to service.

What is the best method for sending/receiving data from control panel to service?

The sockets and named pipes are good, but they may cause windows firewall to show security warnings.
Shared memory also is good, but it requires a lot of synchronization between sending and receiving threads.

Is there any other method that I can use?

Thanks,
Khachatur

Comment: Are you asking how to communicate via IPC of some sort, or how to use the [Service Control Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942(v=vs.85).aspx), or have you considered it as opposed to setting up a socket/pipe infrastructure?

Comment: Have you considered the registry, and [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I am looking for IPC, registry is not good since my app is working under restricted user account and service is working under SYSTEM account.

Comment: Socket/pipe infrastructure also is not good, since Windows Firewall shows a security warning when you try to setup a listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared memory requires three extra mutex objects on each side. Not so much. If you don't want to write anything, our [MsgConnect](https://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) (open-source) implements MMF transport and has a sample of communicating between the service and the UI application.

Comment: Thanks for link, I will check it. According to the documentation, it uses MemoryMappedFile transports and if it does all staff with mutexes, then this is what I am looking for.